# Inline Javascript fadein on pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml, inline, fadein

New to Javascript and trying my best, but can't solve the problem despite extensive searching.

Trying to make an item fadein on page load using inline script (XHTML). I'd love to use external, but can't given software restrictions. Here's the code I've developed so far...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#evan').fadeIn('slow');
});
</script>
<div id='evan' style='position:absolute;left:-200px;top:40%;width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;'></div>
```

While the box does appear, it doesn't fadein so I'm assuming the Javascript isn't written correctly.

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: java and javascript are entirely different

Comment: How about...

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#evan').hide(0).fadeIn('slow');
    });
    </script>
    <div id='evan' style='position:absolute;left:-200px;top:40%;width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;'></div>

Now for a really nub question... does the java portion need to be in the head section, or can that go in the body with the rest? Also, is my use of ' correct or should they be "?

Answer (score 0):

I think for fadeIn to work the item has to be hidden first and your element position (left: -200px) is not within the viewport.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#evan').fadeIn('slow');
});
</script>
<div id='evan' style='position:absolute;top:40%;width:80px;height:80px;background-color:red;display:none'>Some content</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eQzB9/)

Comment: @user2503281 still it may not work because of the position `left:-200px;`

Comment: Yes I understand. It's not an issue as I can see the box. It's just it's not fading in at all. It just appears.

Comment: Well that's great and bad... great because I'm on the right track. Bad because the software I'm using won't read the code correctly. Is there something I'm missing?! Is there something beyond this code I need to do to make it work outside the demo environment?

Comment: Thanks Arun btw for all your help.